# How to get colors and syntax highlighting in Octave?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, octave, color-scheme

I'm a newbie to Octave. When I'm working in Octave, the whole screen is a stream of white on black text, making it difficult to find my previous commands, Octave outputs and code I typed at the Octave prompt.

Is there any configuration I can perform to get some colors in the Octave prompts and messages (like in colorful bash or fish shell) and color syntax highlighting in the Octave code I type at its prompt (like in bpython)?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you on? Linux or Windows?

If you're going to be doing any long-term projects, then I'd suggest to edit in a different editor emacs, vi, or notepad++ (in Windows).

I don't think the Octave interpreter supports syntax highlighting, but you may be able to customize prompt colors:

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Customizing-the-Prompt.html

Answer (score 1):

Please download [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/) if you want an IDE with text editor, syntax highlighting, and more.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about Windows, but on Linux you can use this:

```
printf([char(27), '[94mHello world', char(27), '[0m\n']);
```

Will print blue "Hello world" if your terminal supports colors.

Comment: That's not **shell**; that's specific to the kind of **terminal** you're using.  And it's better to abstract it using a library such as termcap, so you generate the correct codes for the device (or none at all for non-terminal outputs).